# Map coloring with MRV and Degree heuristics in Python

Tags: python, algorithm, graph

I am relatively new to Python. I wrote this solution to the well known map coloring problem and also implemented the MRV and Degree heuristics. Here, I am considering the map of Australia - `['WA', 'NT', 'SA', 'Q', 'NSW', 'V', 'T']` and 3 given colors - `['R','G', 'B']`

```
# choosing first node with degree heruistics
# applying MRV with backtracking

from enum import Enum
import pdb

class Color(Enum):
    RED = 1
    GREEN = 2
    BLUE = 3

class Graph:
    def __init__(self, totalNodes, adjacencyList, color):
        self.totalNodes = totalNodes
        self.adjacencyList = adjacencyList
        self.color = color
        self.nodeSequence = [""]*totalNodes

    def isSafe(self, node, c):
        for i in range(len(self.adjacencyList[node])):
            if(self.color[self.adjacencyList[node][i]] == c):
                return False
        return True


    def graphColorUtil(self, node, colorLimit):
        if node == '':
            # check and color any uncolored node
            for key, value in self.color.items():
                if value == 0:
                    self.graphColorUtil(key, colorLimit)
            return True

        # pdb.set_trace()
        for c in range(1, colorLimit+1):
            if(self.isSafe(node, c) == True):
                self.color[node] = c
                nextNode = self.getNodeWithMRV(node, colorLimit)
                if(self.graphColorUtil(nextNode, colorLimit) == True):
                    return True
                else:
                    self.color[node] = 0

        return False


    def graphColoring(self, colorLimit):
        # pdb.set_trace()
        startNode = self.pickNode('')
        if(self.graphColorUtil(startNode, colorLimit) == True):
            return True
        else:
            print("Solution does not exists")
            return False


    # pick node using MRV
    def pickNode(self, initialNode):
        maxCount = 0
        selectedNode = ''
        # the very first node
        if (initialNode == ''):
            for node, neighbourList in self.adjacencyList.items():
                if (len(neighbourList) > maxCount and self.color[node] == 0):
                    maxCount = len(neighbourList)
                    selectedNode = node
        # the other nodes
        else:
            for i in range(len(self.adjacencyList[initialNode])):
                childNode = self.adjacencyList[initialNode][i]
                if (self.color[childNode] == 0 and len(self.adjacencyList[childNode]) > maxCount):
                    maxCount = len(self.adjacencyList[childNode])
                    selectedNode = childNode

        return selectedNode


    def getNodeWithMRV(self, parentNode, colorLimit):
        selectedNode = ''

        for i in range(len(self.adjacencyList[parentNode])):
            childNode = self.adjacencyList[parentNode][i]
            countColor = 0
            for c in range(1, colorLimit+1):
                if(self.isSafe(childNode, c) == True):
                    countColor += 1
            if (countColor < minCount):
                selectedNode = childNode

        return selectedNode

# driver code
def main():
    adjacencyList = {
        'WA': ['NT', 'SA'],
        'NT': ['WA', 'SA', 'Q'],
        'SA': ['WA', 'NT', 'Q', 'NSW', 'V'],
        'Q': ['NT', 'SA', 'NSW'],
        'NSW': ['SA', 'Q', 'V'],
        'V': ['SA', 'T', 'NSW'],
        'T': ['V']
    };

    color = {
        'WA': 0,
        'NT': 0,
        'SA': 0,
        'Q': 0,
        'NSW': 0,
        'V': 0,
        'T': 0
    };

    g = Graph(7, adjacencyList, color)
    colorLimit = 3
    g.graphColoring(colorLimit)

    for node, color in g.color.items():
        print(node, Color(color).name)
main()
```

What could be the possible ways to refactor this code? I am also interested for feedback on Python code style in general.

Comment: You seem to lose something while copying. How `minCount` ever changes?

Comment: You mean `maxCount` in the `pickNode()` function?

Comment: No. I mean `minCount` in `getNodeWithMRV`

Comment: sorry, `minCount` is unnecessary there. Updated code.

Comment: `if (countColor < minCount):` is still there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although not familiar with MRV and degree heuristics, i can make some remarks about the Python code style:

**Loops can be made more Pythonic**

```
for i in range(len(self.adjacencyList[initialNode])):
    childNode = self.adjacencyList[initialNode][i]
```

should be written as:

```
for childNode in self.adjacencyList[initialNode]:
```

**Conditionals**

```
if(self.isSafe(childNode, c) == True):
```

should be

```
if self.isSafe(childNode, c):
```

**method `isSafe`**

```
def isSafe(self, node, c):
    for i in range(len(self.adjacencyList[node])):
        if(self.color[self.adjacencyList[node][i]] == c):
            return False
    return True
```

could be:

```
def isSafe(self, node, c):
    for adjacency in self.adjacencyList[node]:
        if self.color[adjacency] == c:
            return False
    return True
```

or even, more Pythonic, but a bit cryptic:

```
def isSafe(self, node, c):
    # return True if all node neighbours colors differ from c
    return all([self.color[adj] != c for adj in self.adjacencyList[node]])
```

**Data structure**

The repetition of the keys in the `adjacencyList` and `color`
suggest a data structure like the following, although this requires a 
lot changes in the existing code:

```
nodes = {
    'WA' : {'color' : 0, 'neighbours' : ['NT', 'SA']},
    'NT' : {'color' : 0, 'neighbours' : ['WA', 'SA', 'Q']},
    'SA' : {'color' : 0, 'neighbours' : ['WA', 'NT', 'Q', 'NSW', 'V']},
    'Q'  : {'color' : 0, 'neighbours' : ['NT', 'SA', 'NSW']},
    'NSW': {'color' : 0, 'neighbours' : ['SA', 'Q', 'V']},
    'V'  : {'color' : 0, 'neighbours' : ['SA', 'T', 'NSW']},
    'T'  : {'color' : 0, 'neighbours' : ['V']},
}
```

**Others:**

- `self.nodeSequence` is not used
- `self.totalNodes` is not used
- `minCount = 0` was edited out in `getNodeWithMRV` but should be there, or `if (countColor < minCount)` should be `if (countColor < 0)`
- `pickNode` is called only once with a constant argument `''`, and can therefor be made simpler
- `getNodeWithMRV` will always return `''` because `countColor` will never be smaller than 0.
- the `;` at the end of `adjacencyList = ...` and `color = ...` an origin in another language :-)